# How to read "NA" as a string when importing .csv data ? Without setting na.strings = ""

Tags: r, string, na

I have a file with "NA" values (string values) that are read as missing values when I use the fread function. Is there a way to say not to read "NA" as a missing value ? I do not want to use na.strings = ""

Comment: 1) A few lines of your file would be helpful to know how your data looks. 2) Why you don't want to use `na.strings = ""` ?

Comment: Because I have a lot of empty fields and if I use  na.strings = "" they will be read as NA values and I would have several error/problems with the merging of tables.